# typescript: use cdk to create multiple s3 buckets in a for loop

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am not sure if this is feasible, but I want to create multiple buckets in a for loop.
Reason is I need let's say 10 buckets, they all have same configurations but different name. The bucket name is based on an array.

For example with given array [apple, banana, peach, pear, lemon], the bucket name will be s3bucketfor_apple, s3bucketfor_banana, s3bucketfor_peach, s3bucketfor_pear, s3bucketfor_lemon

I am thinking if this can be done in a for loop because every configurations are same except for the name.

Does anybody know how to do so?

Thank you!

Comment: Asking how to do so wont help instead what did you tried? are you facing any error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop (for each) over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/loop-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Create a function of creating S3 bucket

```
export const CreateBucket = function (
  scope: Construct,
  bucketName: string,
  expireDays?: number,
  noBlockPublic?: boolean,
): Bucket {

  let bucket = new Bucket(
    scope,
    bucketName,
    {
      bucketName: bucketName,
      encryption: BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
      enforceSSL: true,
      blockPublicAccess: noBlockPublic ? undefined : BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
    },
  );
  if (expireDays && expireDays > 0) {
    bucket.addLifecycleRule({
      id: 'delete-old-object',
      expiration: Duration.days(expireDays),
    });
  }
  return bucket;
}

['bucket1', 'bucket2'].foreach(s3name => {
  CreateBucket(this, name);
})
```